# error: illegal assignment from string to decimal

Tags: apex, sobject

```
public class DemoSObject {
    public void Demomethod(){
        SObject obj;
        obj = new Account(Name = 'Test', phone = '998877');        
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test' ;
        acc.phone = '889977';
        system.debug('acc =>' +acc);

        obj = new student__c(Name='Test',high_school_phone__c='998877');
        //std.Name = 'Test';
        //std.high_school_phone__c = '998877';
        student__c std = (student__c)obj;
        system.debug('std => '+std);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is straightforward here. What part of it are you having trouble understanding? What have you tried to do to resolve the issue so far?

Comment: obj = new student__c(Name='Test',high_school_phone__c='998877');

Comment: I think i went wrong in the above statement. can you tell me is any other way to assign values?

Comment: If high_school_phone__c is a Number field (and not a text field, like the standard Phone datatype), you will need to assign without single quotes (like high_school_phone__c=998877).

Comment: yes i got it . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To access a field on sObject (aside from Id), you need to use the get and put methods:

```
obj = new student__c(Name='Test',high_school_phone__c='998877');
std.put('Name','Test');
std.put('high_school_phone__c','998877');
```

Based on your description, it sounds like you made High School Phone a *number* field, not a Phone field, so you can't use quotes:

```
obj = new student__c(Name='Test',high_school_phone__c=998877);
std.put('Name','Test');
std.put('high_school_phone__c',998877);
```